# HTML file is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two version of the same code.
When I added it in the code snippet from this page it's working pretty well. However, for some reason I cannot get it working it working in my computer.

Take a look in my [Dropbox version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39041929/site/MapaTravessia/Examples/test3.html) to get some idea. It's the same coding I'm using in both cases. It's supposed to check a parent checkbox if the child checkbox is checked and vice-versa.

Do you guys have some idea why is it happening?

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    var sibs = false;
    $(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
        if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
    })
    $(this).parents('ul').prev().prop('checked', sibs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="account_settings" value="yes">Account Settings
        <!-- AND SHOULD CHECK HERE -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one">AS One</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="two" value="two">AS Two</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="user_roles" value="user_roles">Users &amp; Roles
                <!-- SHOULD CHECK HERE -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="add">Add</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_role" value="delete">Delete</li>
                    <!-- CHECK HERE -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rl_module" value="yes">RL Module</li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rl_module" value="yes">Accounting
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vat" value="yes">VAT</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="bank_account" value="yes">Banking
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="view" value="yes">View</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="crud" value="yes">CRUD</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: open your browser developer console and look for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting your script after the body? (You can leave the script tag where it loads the jQuery in the head)
I used your code and just put your script after the body and it worked just fine.
I had that issue aswell where the script wouldn't work when placed before the body.
Let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: Oh man!! Tks! I've never seen it before, but it worked though! haha

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the above snippet not working is "events not getting attached" to the element. Try opening the debugger tool here in the page and to one in the dropbox, you will find there is no events attached to the Dropbox's element.

You can use `on` to attach the events to overcome this situation.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function () {
$(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
var sibs = false;
$(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
    if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
})
$(this).parents('ul').prev().prop('checked', sibs);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, though. The only thing that appears in the Console.log is: "NO OEMBED"